# Having IIS remote management problem with my vista machine managing Server 2008 IIS 7.5

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, web-server, windows-vista

I am trying to use IIS 7 Remote Management installed on Vista Ultimate SP1. Connection is to IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 Webserver R2. Tried on both full & core install.
When I connect up, the console wants to download and install new features.

Microsoft.Web.Management.IisClient 7.5.0.0
Microsoft.Web.Management.AspnetClient 7.5.0.0

I check the boxes and click OK and it downloads them and asks if I want to install them, but after I click run it just quits. I tried just choosing one or the other, same thing. I ran IIS Remote tool as administrator. These features installed correctly on my XP machine. Any ideas?

UPDATE : If I had any Rep I would offer like 500 rep to get this fixed!

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug that was fixed in Windows Vista SP2, if you install it your problem will be fixed.
Alternatively you can just delete four files that are located at \windows\system32\inetsrv\ directory:
Microsoft.Web.Management.AspnetClient.dll
Microsoft.Web.Management.Aspnet.dll
Microsoft.Web.Management.IisClient.dll
Microsoft.Web.Management.Iis.dll

Deleting this files will require you to take ownership of them:
   (right-click -> properties -> security -> advanced -> owner -> Edit)
   then set owner to administrators, click ok and close all dialogs.
Add permissions for you
   (right-click -> properties -> security -> edit -> add full permissions for administrators).

Finally delete the files, this change will not cause any side effects and will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will work or install but you can try the [Windows 7 Remote Administration Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=7d2f6ad7-656b-4313-a005-4e344e43997d#tm). These definitly include the management tools for R2 including IIS 7.5. However I am not sure if it will install on Wibdows Vista. I suspect the official Vista tools will be released when the Server hits public RTM.